# Show duplicate IDs in chrome dev console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to get the chrome dev console to warn you about duplicate IDs on a page? I can't tell you how many times I've been stumped by an issue only to finally realize that 2 elements are sharing the same id and messing up the code. Does anyone have any other suggestions on how to catch things like this as well that chrome doesn't seem to warn about by default?

Answer (score 13):

Running this in devtools will print them out

```js
const dupes = Object.entries(
    [...document.querySelectorAll("[id]")]
      .map((x) => x.id) /* get all ids */
      .reduce(
        (acc, id) => ({ ...acc, [id]: (acc[id] || 0) + 1 }),
        {}
      ) /*count them*/
  ).filter(([_key, val]) => val > 1); /* find the ones repeating more than once */
  
console.warn(dupes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Chrome's developer's console doesn't provide a feature for doing that.

However, there is a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dup-id-scans-html-for-dup/nggpgolddgjmkjioagggmnmddbgedice) that can do it for you.

Comment: This extension is delisted now.